# I have RecyclerView and Bottom app bar but it doesn't show bottom app bar

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-bottomappbar

I have RecyclerView and Bottom app bar but it doesn't show bottom app bar.what should i add to my code?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/appbar"/>
    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"/>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_app_bar">
    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Share the screenshot, please.

Comment: Try to give `BottomNavigationView` a width and height and see if it shows

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/recycler"/>
```